# Next JS 13 create Progress bar

Tags: reactjs, next.js, chakra-ui

I've tried to implement progress bar to my Next JS 13 app dir. but the old ways is not working. is there a way for progress bar to work? i've used `NextNProgress` and `NProgress` packages. but non of them worked. i even tried to create my own from scratch using `next/route` and `Chakraui` progress. but no luck

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    Router.events.on("routeChangeStart", () => setIsLoading(true));
    Router.events.on("routeChangeComplete", () => setIsLoading(false));
    Router.events.on("routeChangeError", () => setIsLoading(false));
  }, [Router]);
```

this was the method i used

```
<ChakraProvider>
   {isLoading && <Progress value={40} height={1} />}
   {children}
</ChakraProvider>
```

page.jsx

```
    "use client";
import { ChakraProvider } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import "../styles/globals.css";
import NextNProgress from "nextjs-progressbar";
import { wrapper } from "../store";
import { Progress } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Router from "next/router";
// import NProgress from "nprogress";
// import "nprogress/nprogress.css";

// Router.events.on("routeChangeStart", () => NProgress.start());
// Router.events.on("routeChangeComplete", () => NProgress.done());
// Router.events.on("routeChangeError", () => NProgress.done());

function RootLayout({ children }) {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    Router.events.on("routeChangeStart", () => setIsLoading(true));
    Router.events.on("routeChangeComplete", () => setIsLoading(false));
    Router.events.on("routeChangeError", () => setIsLoading(false));
  }, [Router, isLoading]);
  return (
    <html>
      <head />
      <body className="max-w-7xl mx-auto">
        {/* <NextNProgress /> */}
        <ChakraProvider>
          {isLoading && <Progress value={40} height={1} />}
          {/* <NextNProgress color="red" /> */}
          {children}
        </ChakraProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

export default wrapper.withRedux(RootLayout);
```

Comment: you should create a reproducible repo.

Comment: i can add the whole `page.jsx` file

Comment: Smaller alternative to NProgress: https://gist.github.com/tkrotoff/db8a8106cc93ae797ea968d78ea28047

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, trying to render `{children}` might be causing your issue. The `page.jsx` file does not have children.

Comment: so how can i make use of these?

Answer (score 0):

I use `nextjs-toploader` with no problems.
Inside `app/layout.jsx` file:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import NextTopLoader from 'nextjs-toploader';

export default function Layout({ children, user }) {
   ...
return (
<html id="pageRoot">
  <body className="...">
    <NextTopLoader />
    ...
  </body>
</html>
)}
```

You can walk through that library code and create your own.

Comment: this library is useless because it does not work with router.push